# iuvare ut + subjunctive

Tags: syntax, conjunctive, purpose-clause, ut

In English, I might ask you to "help me [to] do" some task. Would the most (classically) idiomatic Latin equivalent be an ut clause (e.g., "iuva ut faciam ...")? My only reason for hesitancy is that whereas the English suggests collaboration in the "doing," the Latin seems perhaps to say that *I* (as the grammatical subject of the subordinate clause) am "doing" while *you* are merely "helping." Am I reading too much into this syntactic difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that *iuvare ut* + subjunctive is *not* the most idiomatic equivalent. In fact, Lewis & Short do not even mention this construction in [their entry for *iuvare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Djuvo). You can certainly say it, but I feel the meaning would be more like "assist me so that I may do task X or Y."

No, I think *adiuvare in aliqua re* or *ad aliquam rem* is the way to go. In particular, it is often used with gerund(ive)s or other kinds of verbal nouns, e.g.:

> Help me lift that box.
> *Me adiuves ad illam cistam tollendam.*

There are numerous ways to use *adiuvare*, including *ut/ne* + subjunctive, a plain infinitive and more. But the above seems to me the most common and straightforward translation of *help [to] do*.

Comment: Multas gratias pro consilio tuo. For what it's worth, I was going mainly by the OLD entry for iuvo, which gives the ut construction as a possibility - but it hadn't occurred to me to look under adiuvo!